# Iterating over multiple rows of data in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0, sqlclient

I'm writing some PowerShell code to connect to a database, read multiple rows of data, and return them back via a `SqlDataReader`.

I did this "the C# way" by writing it how I would write this in C#:

```
function ExecuteQuery($sql) {
    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString);
    $connection.Open();

    $cmd = $connection.CreateCommand();
    $cmd.CommandText = $sql;
    $cmd.Connection = $connection    
    $reader = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader]$cmd.ExecuteReader()
    return $reader;
}
```

(The caller of this function has to close the connection themselves responsibly.)

I expected, even without the typecast, that I would get an instance of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`. This is important, because I want to use `Read` to iterate through row by row, not to mention that I want to use square-brackets to access data by column name (accessing by ID is too fragile).

Unfortunately, I get back an instance of `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal`, which does *not* contain a `Read` method, nor does it allow me to access records by array index.

My question is: how can I read and iterate through multiple rows of data in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to iterate through members of an array ('rows of data' in your case). The first that comes to mind is:

```
ForEach($Record in (ExecuteQuery $CommandString){
    Do Stuff to $Record
}
```

Or you could pipe it to a ForEach loop (you can pipe output this way, such as to Out-File if desired):

```
ExecuteQuery $CommandString | ForEach{Do stuff to $_}
```

Or if you really want more granular control I suppose you could use a For loop and do something like:

```
$Results = ExecuteQuery $CommandString 
For($i=0;$i -le $Results.count;$i++){
    Do stuff to $Results[$i]
}
```

Comment: +1 works great, thanks. Just like C#, I can use `$record[0]` or `$record['FirstName']`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PowerShell is trying to enumerate the reader for you when the function returns it. You can tell PowerShell to leave it alone by putting it into an array:

```
return ,$reader
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my question clearly? I am returning `$reader`. In C#, the equivalent code to what I have here returns an instance of `SqlDataReader`, which can be enumerated and has a `Read` function.

Comment: I know. That's one of the quirks of PowerShell that got me coming from .NET. PowerShell won't obey you and return `$reader` as you've told it to; instead it tries to enumerate the reader for you, returning `Object[]` instead. Check the return type of your `ExecuteReader` function as it was in your original question. `ExecuteQuery($sql).GetType().FullName` will return `Object[]`. But if you force `$reader` into an array, PowerShell will leave it alone, and the return type will be `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` as expected. Crazy? I think so, but that's PowerShell!

Comment: I actually did check, and (read my question again) typecast the type from `ExecuteReader`. It's a `DataRecordInternal`, not a `SqlDataReader`. Stuffing it into an array didn't change that. Maybe you're not using PowerShell 3?

Comment: With PowerShell 3, your **function's** return type is `System.Object[]`. I don't mean the type of `$reader` *inside* the function. I mean what the function actually returns. I know it's counterintuitive, but run `ExecuteQuery($YourSqlHere).GetType().FullName` and you'll see what I mean. PowerShell is trying to enumerate the reader when it returns it, which is why casting beforehand doesn't help. To *stop* that, you do have to put the reader into an array: `return ,$reader`. That changes the return value of the function not into an array (as we'd expect coming from C#) but to `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: By the way, that should be `(ExecuteQuery $YourSqlHere).GetType().FullName` above. I was writing C# myself!

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Unfortunately, like my first comment indicates, returning an array didn't change the type to `SqlDataReader` from `DataRecordInternal`. It's still evaluated. I used the accepted answer to iterate.

Comment: Well, main thing is it's working! Still, my geeky side's curious why it's different on our shells. Did you make `$reader` the second item of the array like in my answer? `return ,$reader`? Returning `@($reader)` doesn't do the trick, but making it the second item makes the return type `SqlDataReader` for me.